# Is there a way of writing CSS that lets you re-organize the order of how HTML components appear?

Tags: css, mobile, desktop, responsive

I am working on a responsive site in which the mobile/tablet view differs from the desktop view in the way it re-orders the DIVs.

Is there a way to write maintainable CSS that let's you re-organize the order of how HTML DIVs appear?

For example, the code below controls the order of how DIVs would appear on a desktop device:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row1">
        <div class="col1A">Sample content</div>
        <div class="col2A">Sample content</div>
        <div class="col3A">Sample content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row2">
        <div class="col1B">Sample content</div>
        <div class="col2B">Sample content</div>
        <div class="col3B">Sample content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, for mobile/tablet view, I want to display the DIVs in different order using CSS, like the example below:

Show row2, col2B 
Then row1, col1A 
Then row1, col3A 
Then row2, col1B

Is this possible using CSS ?

Comment: Where is your CSS?

Answer (score 2):

As a proof-of-concept, you can use the `flex` CSS property to reorder how elements are visually rendered.

In your example, I had to keep the child elements within a single container
and then I could control the order using the `order` property.

If you want to hide some items on the small screen view, use `display: none` on the specific items.

Note: For a wide screen, you would need some CSS rules to get the items to look like two rows. (Please specify what you need.)

If you combine this with media queries, you can get a workable solution.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}
.container div {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px dotted gray;
  width: auto;
}
.col1A {
  order: 2;
}
.col2A {
  display: none;
}
.col3A {
  order: 3;
}
.col1B {
  order: 4;
}
.col2B {
  order: 1;
}
.col3B {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="row1 col1A">Sample content 1A</div>
  <div class="row1 col2A">Sample content 2A</div>
  <div class="row1 col3A">Sample content 3A</div>

  <div class="row2 col1B">Sample content 1B</div>
  <div class="row2 col2B">Sample content 2B</div>
  <div class="row2 col3B">Sample content 3B</div>

</div>
```

If you want to simulate two rows of three elements, you can still use `flex` with some adjustments. The following may be helpful.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
.container .row1 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.container div {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px dotted gray;
  flex-basis: calc(33% - 20px);
}
.col1B {
  background-color: yellow;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="row1 col1A">Sample content 1A</div>
  <div class="row1 col2A">Sample content 2A</div>
  <div class="row1 col3A">Sample content 3A</div>

  <div class="row2 col1B">Sample content 1B</div>
  <div class="row2 col2B">Sample content 2B</div>
  <div class="row2 col3B">Sample content 3B</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I'll test out the above code snippets to see if the flex and order properties are supported by the major browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Set a screen size for mobile device detection in the css and add the following

```
@media screen and (max-width: SIZE) {
    .row2{
        display: flex; flex-flow: column;
    }

    .col1B{
        order: 1;
    }

    .col2B{
        order: 2;
    }

    .col3B{
        order: 3;
    }
}
```

And then add the classes to the DIVs

```
   <div class="row2">
        <div class="col1B">Sample content</div>
        <div class="col2B">Sample content</div>
        <div class="col3B">Sample content</div>
    </div>
```

Change `order: 1/2/3;` to your needs.